# Update all records through model relation ship in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
class ModelA {
   public function modelB()
   {
      return $this->hasMany(ModelB::class);
   }
}

class ModelB {
  public function modelC()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(ModelC::class);
  }
}

class ModelC {
  public function modelD()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(ModelD::class);
  }
}

class ModelD {
  //has column status_changed_date
}
```

I have `$modelA = ModelA::find($id);`
ModelA have multiple ModelB, ModelB have multiple ModelC, ModelC has multiple ModelD.
Now I want update status_changed_date for all matching records. 
Is there any better way to do this. I have refered https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships
but couldn't find out a solution.
Please help to solve this.

Comment: You can try nested relationship : `ModelA::with('modelB.modelC.modelD')->find($id)`;

Comment: yeah, but how can I update my field in ModelD?

Answer (score 0):

`$modelAs = ModelA::with('modelB.modelC.modelD')->find($id)`

before you can use that way :

```
$modelA->modelB->each->modelC->each->modelC->each->update([
     'field' => 'value'
]);
```

or reduce values to ids, this only made one query :

```
$ids = [];
$modelA->modelB->each->modelC->each->modelC->each(function ($c) use($ids) {
    $ids[] = $c->id;
});
ModelC::whereIn('id', $ids)->update([
   'field' => 'value'
});
```

if `each->modelC->each` is not working, use method notation

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: It looping a lot. :(

Comment: For the first method but the the second one is more efficiant, because there is only one query at the end
(i've added the use statement on the function)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making all this update, make one common table of common fields and directly update that table.

For more
[Laravel Polyformic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)